# I have to Disable Minimizing function of my Flutter App(android), how can I do that?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, operating-system, minimize

I'm working on a flutter project wherein I need to disable the minimize function (both swipe up and button) focused on Android. How can I implement it programmatically? Also, it has to be enabled when required.

Thanks in Advance :)

I tried using AppLifeCycleState, willpopscope (actually I disables backpress button thankfully), Android System UI and System UI Overlays. Nothing worked